# How to plot a several functions in matlab for n converges to infinity?

Tags: matlab, function, plot

Can anybody help me and tell me how to plot these functions in `matlab`:

1. `n!*log(n)`
2. `sqr(n)`
3. `(n+1)!`
4. `log^2(n)`
5. `n`
6. `log(n^n)`

Where *n* is a natural number and converges to infinity?

Comment: there's a problem to plot functions that don't converge at infinity (all of them are infinite @ infinity) , what exactly do you want? have you tried reading basic matlab documentation?

Answer (score 1):

The plots don't look pretty due to the high numbers, but this is how:

```
n=logspace(1,10,10);
plot(n,factorial(n).*log(n));
```

For the first one. By sqr I'm guessing you mean the square root, in which case sqrt(n) should be used.